# What can I use to control the passage of 3.3 V to a PCB pad

Tags: voltage, power, switches

I am building a PCB that will extend upon an existing device.

In this PCB there is a section that basically takes an existing switch in the device and expands it into this new PCB via a switch.

Now, I was wondering if by using an Arduino GPIO, I could somehow control this connection as well, meaning I would be able to trigger the device switch via code.

A diagram can be seen below:

[image]

Since the Arduino can emit 3.3 V (VCC used) and be pulled to low on the GPIO pin, I draw it as a pulse signal with peak 3.3 V.

I thought about using a simple diode just to protect the GPIO pin and that it should suffice but I am wondering if I could use something else that would take the same 3.3 V from the original switch pin and allow it to pass based on the GPIO pin voltage.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying that the original device has a switch, and your PCB adds an additional switch in parallel with the original one, and you'd like to add a third device which acts as a switch in parallel with the first two switches. Is that correct? What sort of power or signal is the switch switching? If it's simply switching 3.3 V power, that's pretty easy to do; if it's switching, say, 120 V AC, that's still possible, but it'll require a different solution.

Comment: Its only allowing the passage of 3.3v. More info is that this is a button already existing in the device. It takes 3.3v on one of the pins and when connected it activates the buttons action. The first extension is merely to pull the switch into the new format for the device (its a mod). Now I also wanted the possibility of activating this switch via an arduino that I include in the new PCB. Basically we would have the original button (no longer used), the new parallel switch (acting as the new used switch with same functionality) and the same but GPIO activated. Hope this helps

Comment: It also means that as soon as 3.3v and current are supplied to the upper wire, the button is activated on the device and needs to be released before re activating it [hence the pulse idea, which would just be turning the GPIO pin low/high] I thought about a NPN transistor, but the emitter would already be at 3.3v and the pad connected to it would always have 3.3v, the only thing is that I could turn it on to make it go to ground?

Comment: If you want high-side switching like this without the drive complexity that comes with using n-type devices on the high side, you need a p-type pass device (either a pnp bjt or a p-channel mosfet).

Comment: Alternatively, you could use an n-channel depletion mode device (either a depletion mode MOSFET or a JFET), but that way the switch will act like it's always pressed when the arduino is powered off or not connected, which I expect you don't want.

Comment: @Hearth yes, I want basically to toggle the 3.3v but the default behavior should be as if it was disconnected. Wondering, how would I wire it in that case? I can grab a GND src but basically the device is already attempting to pull up current as soon as the 3.3v establish connection.

Comment: You can achieve that with a p-type pass device, as my first comment said. Your descriptions of what's happening are very hard to follow. What does "attempting to pull up current" mean? What's a "GND src"?

Comment: @Hearth what I mean is that as soon as 3.3v are measured on the pad, the original switch will activate, thus I am wondering how the wiring of the p mosfet would go in the above diagram I posted. I am guessing that Gate would be the GPIO pin, source would be the connection to the pad that goes to the original switch and 3.3v would go into the drain terminal?